# `standardEndpoint` causing Exception `A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI ...`

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-8

I'm using ASP.Net routing to host service on `127.0.0.1` (in Win8+IIS8) like

```
WebServiceHostFactory factory = new WebServiceHostFactory();
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("Services/ABC/", factory, typeof(ABCService)));
```

And default behavior for endpoints like

```
<standardEndpoints>
    <webHttpEndpoint>
        <standardEndpoint helpEnabled="false"
                          automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true"
                          faultExceptionEnabled="false"
                          crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true"
                          defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"
                          hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                          transferMode="Streamed">
            <security mode="None" />
        </standardEndpoint>
    </webHttpEndpoint>
</standardEndpoints>
```

These settings are causing a error `A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI 'http://<MachineName>/Services/IMAPI/'. If two endpoints want to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of AddServiceEndpoint() and config.`

I'm not sure about this error, why it is occurring as i'm not experienced in WCF but this error goes on removing web.config's configuration of standardEndpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your service URI to other port. As example to port 28900 or else.